# How to use IN CONDITION in django Aggregation

Tags: python, django, aggregation

How can I use IN condition (example: SELECT SUM(a) FROM b WHERE a IN (1, 2, 3))
by using Django Aggregation.

Example:

```
result = qs.aggregate(  
    amount = SUM(Case(WHEN('a IN(1, 2, 3)', then=Value(a)), default=0))
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The same way you do any other [`in` queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#in):

```
from django.db.models import Case, Sum, When, Value

result = qs.aggregate(
    amount=Sum(Case(When(a__in=[1, 2, 3], then=Value(a)), default=0))
)
```